# What part of the name should be used to refer to someone?

Tags: names

When we want to talk about someone without giving their full name, in contexts where in English we would use the family name, what part of the name should we use?

I'm confused since adjectives are sometimes derived from nomen, sometimes from cognomen.

- *ciceronianus* < Marcus Tullius Cicero
- *virgilianus* < Publius Vergilius Maro

Comment: [*tullianus*](https://www.google.de/books/edition/D_Erasmi_Dialogus_Ciceronianus_sive_de_o/LBRmAAAAcAAJ?hl=de&gbpv=1&dq=tulliana&pg=PA199&printsec=frontcover) < Marcus Tullius Cicero. (By the way, the title of this work is “Ciceronianus” ).

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Well that's confusing